# Css Selector has specific attribute?

Tags: java, css, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I need to click the checkboxes from a collection if they are not checked by default as well some other conditions. And backward too. So, i need to find out if the CSS selector has checked attribute or not. How can i write java code/ css selector for that? HTML code is as below:

```
<input name="name1" checked="checked" id="id1" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

I have severals elements which i can define as List elements. But from that list, How can i find out which element is already checked??? I know i can define webelements for only checked elements. But in that case, i will loose the options to check uncheck. I am looking for something like this:

```
boolean boolV = chkboxes.get(i).hasAttribute("checked");
```

Or some other way???

Answer (score 0):

To find out which checkbox is selected or not, we can use this method in selenium:

```
boolean boolV = chkboxes.get(i).isSelected();
```

This will return true if the checkbox is already selected.